# handle fast api calling the same query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter

Hi how do I handle fast api calling the same query. here is the scenario I have an api url

example.com/send_sms?apikey=abcdef&contact=123123123&text=your+is+otp+112233

when my client call url this it will check this user whether have enough credit in his account before sending the sms out. I have been using this method for years however just yesterday one of my client keep spamming my server due to their programming logic .

below is my php method and Mysql user credit table

```
function send_sms(){
       
        $api_key = $this->input->get_post('apikey',TRUE);

        $user_credit = '';
        $this->db->select('SUM(credit) as total_credit');
        $this->db->from('users_credit');
        $this->db->where('apikey' , $api_key);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $user_credit = $query->row()->total_credit;

        // assume we already assigned value to $sms_credit
       if ($sms_credit <= $user_credit) {
          // message send
       }else{
          //message cannot send
       }

}
```

```
CREATE TABLE `users_credit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `apikey` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `credit` decimal(50,2) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I check my mysql process list it creates a lot of the processes which slowdown mysql. \

I cannot slowdown customer calling our api because SMS especially OTP(One Time Password) must be processed instantly.

I wonder what should i do to optimize this query ? should i add another column to store last customer credit ?

Comment: Is there a single API key per user? We need more context.

Comment: Creating an index on the `apiKey` column might improve the performance, but apart from that, there's little you can do in your code. You could use redis to store the results temporarily or use varnish to cache the output of your pages.

Comment: @nice_dev yes single API key per user

Comment: You could put your own limit on requests to _your_ server from your clients.

Comment: Just wondering, does the users_credit table contain multiple rows with 'credit' that together make up the 'total_credit' amount? If not, I wonder what the SUM() function is used for.

Comment: @maikucao Did you review the answer? Did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Optimization recommendations based on the current context:

- Index your `apikey` column for faster lookup.

  ```
   alter table `users_credit`
   add index `apiKey_index` (apiKey)
  ```
- Don't make multiple rows with same api key for a user but different credit score and summing that all up in the end. Instead store the total credit once and keep decrementing from this row using transaction like below. When it reaches `0`, deny the service.

  ```
  START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE `users_credit`
  SET credit = credit - YOUR_AMOUNT
  WHERE apikey = 'your_key';
  COMMIT;
  ```
- This way, you can solve the race condition problems too and save a lot of memory being occupied on the disk by having only a single row per API key.
- Also have API rate limit rules for your customers based on per minute/ per hour/ per account etc so that they don't overload your servers with their requests(either genuinely or any spam-bot wise). Many big companies do adopt this approach to avoid any kind of DDOS or DOS attack at the very basic level.

You can look at [`Facebook rate limiting approach`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/) and implement something similar.

Comment: A single statement does not need the Start/Commit (assuming `autocommit=ON`.

Comment: @RickJames Yeah, I just added it just to be sure.